# Some files disappear after downloading from Chrome in Linux Mint 17.1 x64

Tags: linux, google-chrome, linux-mint, download

**TL;DR**

Some pdf file exists, but it won't show in file explorer, nor in terminal.

--

Sometimes, when I download a file using Chrome (v. 59, 60 etc.), it is saved in my download directory, then it disappears.

It seems to happen only **sometimes**, if the file is `.pdf` and is downloaded from my gmail, from Chrome x64, under Linux Mint 17.1 x64.

The download directory is in another NTFS partition. When I remount the partition, nothing changes.

The crazy thing is that the file is still accessible from, say, chrome downloads page, but the file disappears from the file explorer. Not even in terminal can I see the file, using `ls -a`, but if I try to delete/move/copy it, it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fill a bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1275937/files-that-begin-with-w-disappears-from-file-explorer-in-nemo-cinammon).

The reason is that there were non-obvious errors with the NTFS partition. I think something to do with Windows not closing the FS properly.

After formatting that partition to ext3, there seems to be no more problem.