# Files that begin with w disappears from file explorer in nemo cinammon

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, linux-mint, cinnamon, nemo

In the directory "Downloads" (NTFS partition), if a file is created and it's name starts with `w`, it will disappear after refresh.

I don't know if this happens in any other directory, but I haven't found any.

I cannot see the file even in terminal. But I can open it, and delete it.

Any ideas?

Details:

System: Linux Mint Cinnamon 17, x64.
Partition: NTFS
File Explorer: Nemo

Comment: "I cannot see the file even in terminal" – do you mean `ls` doesn't print it? or what?

Comment: This combined with your other question https://superuser.com/questions/1275709/my-system-became-suddenly-read-only suggest you have logical and/or physical errors in your drives.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, `ls`, nor `ls -la`, nor `dir`

Comment: @MichaelBay I dont know. The read-only thing happened for the 1st time in 2 years. But the `w` disappearing has happened since before.I don't know.

Comment: Ok, but why only with files which have names starting with `w`? Why only in one directory? How it is possible not to appear, but to be accessible from any program?

Comment: Error in NTFS drives may look like that. *Why* is not that relevant. *How* to check and correct the errors is what matters. You need Windows to correct NTFS drives (the Linux tools are very limited) but checking the health of the drives can be done with Disks or any other (GUI or CLI) tool in Linux. It certainly looks like your drive(s) is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that there were non-obvious errors with the NTFS partition. Probably something to do with Windows not closing the FS properly.

After formatting that partition to ext3, there seems to be no more problem.

`chkdsk` from windows didn't fix the errors. Nor did `ntfsfix` from linux.